# How to add certificates to an existing PKCS#7 bundle (p7b) file?

Tags: openssl, certificate

I have a PKCS#7 bundle (p7b file) that holds many public S/MIME certificates, and I need two more certificates in the bundle.

Is there a way to add these certificates using openssl (or possibly keytool) without having to recreate the bundle from scratch?